# Can't get Result of Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending a request to a php file from a form using Ajax. And I want to receive a result from this php file.

Here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#devis_gratuit').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.getJSON(
                'mail.php', {
                    prestation: $('.prestation-input').val(),
                    heures: $('.heures-input').val(),
                    nom: $('.nom-input').val(),
                    ville: $('.ville-input').val(),
                    prenom: $('.prenom-type').val(),
                    code_postal: $('.code_postal-input').val(),
                    tel: $('.tel-input').val(),
                    email: $('.email-status').val()},

                    function(data){
                        alert("A"); //Doesn't work
                        $('#status').hide();
                        $('#status').html('')
                            .append('<b>Paramètre en majuscule</b> : '+data.response+'<br/>');                   
                        $('#status').fadeIn();
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and my php code **mail.php**:

```
if(isset($_GET['prestation'])
    && isset($_GET['heures'])
    && isset($_GET['nom'])
    && isset($_GET['prenom'])
    && isset($_GET['ville'])
    && isset($_GET['code_postal'])
    && isset($_GET['tel'])
    && isset($_GET['email'])) 
{
    $response = "Ok";
    die($response); //Doesn't work
}
else {
    $response = "Ko";
    die($response); //Doesn't work
}

$return = array('response' => $response);
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

But it looks like it's not getting on the PHP file and I see on firebug that the request is Sent successfully. Any help please ? Thank you.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there si any error

Comment: `$.getJSON` needs response in json and you are returning array but before this  you have also used `die()` why ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you. There is no errors. I can also see that the request has been sent successfully `http://127.0.0.1/landing/mail.php?prestation=reguliere&heures=12&nom=hatake&ville=La+courneuve&prenom=kakashi&code_postal=93120&tel=0628206961&email=bendrissmehdi%40gmail.com`

@dianuj thank you. But it should at least show me the response value..

Comment: i just echo my data and finish with `exit();` and then read the html data in and convert if necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you use `die()` in PHP, you are returning a 500 response code to the client.  Therefore you will never enter the anonymous `success` function in your `getJSON` code.

In other words, to get the alert in the following code snippet, you need to return a successful response code (2xx):

```
$.getJSON(
    'mail.php', 
    {...},
    function(data){
        alert("A");
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. But I've used die to only see if `$response` contains anything, and it looks that the php file has not been read, that's the problem (even without using `die` it doesn't return anything)

Comment: How would `die()` help you in seeing that the PHP is executed?  Since it is an AJAX call, `die()` wouldn't output anything to the screen.  It would only show up in the AJAX response.  So you would have to take a look at Firebug to see if your 500 response contains the text "KO" or "OK".

Comment: Thank you steve. But I don't get a 500 Error, I only Get a 200 code response OK.. with this url `http://127.0.0.1/landing/mail.php?prestation=reguliere&heures=12&nom=hatake&vil‌​le=La+courneuve&prenom=kakashi&code_postal=93120&tel=0628206961&email=bendrissmeh‌​di%40gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `die` and use `json_encode($return);` and check again as your response should be in `json` format.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did but it doesn't show me the alert.. Any idea ??

Comment: Can you now see the response in firbug console? If so then try to alert(data.response) and check.

Answer (score 0):

You did not get json format from server.

Just change

```
$response = "Ok";
die($response);
```

to

```
$response[] = "Ok";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried with `$response[] = "Ok";
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);` It gives me the `Alert ('A')` but the `data.response` as undefined. 
So Ihave tried with : `$response = array("response" => "Ok")` and finally works.
Thank you.